# R: Extracting elements for loop from lapply object

Tags: r, for-loop, machine-learning, lapply

In short: is there a way to loop through each element of the lapply object described below `allModelsResults` ?

Meaning, `allModelsResults$'1'` for example gives me 1st element from the object. Next `allModelsResults$'2'` would be the 2nd element. I would like to create a `for` loop in order to extract each element, run some commands, and store the results.

Detailed description below...

I have the following code, where I run a simple ML model using "knn" across multiple model specifications. The model specifications are stored in `allModelList`, and all the results are stored in `allModelsResults`.

An single model from all model list looks like:

```
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3
```

or

```
y ~ x1 + x5 + x4
```

and so on... in short a series of combinations of model specifications

```
allModelsResults <- lapply(allModelsList, function(x) train(x,       data=All_categories_merged_done,method = "knn"))
```

I would like to now extract each element (results from each model) one by one to run analysis on. For example I can manually take:

`allModelsResults$'1'` to get results from the first model, or `allModelsResults$'5'` to et results from the 5th model and so on.

I ideally I would loop through these in a for loop, were each time I select one of the elements are run a series of commands on.

Any help on how to extract the elements from allModelsResults object would really help! I have about 50 model specifications, so I need to create a loop or something similar to extract one by one automatically.

Specifically in order to share for the community, for each element I would like to do this one by one for each model.

As an example I am extracting model 1 here (this does not work obviously):

```
aggregate_results <- NULL

for(z in 1:length(categories)){
element_number_ID <- (element_number[z])
```

`element_number_ID` should equal `'1'` to extract the right model

```
    model_1_result <- allModelsResults$'1'

    ResultsTestPred <- predict(model_1_result, testing_data)
    results_to_store <- confusionMatrix(ResultsTestPred, testing_data $outcome)

aggregate_results  <- rbind(aggregate_results, results_to_store)

}
```

`results_to_store` output for one element looks like:

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

```
      Reference
```

Prediction  0  1
         0 14  2
         1  4 19

```
           Accuracy : 0.8462          
             95% CI : (0.6947, 0.9414)
No Information Rate : 0.5385          
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.00005274      

              Kappa : 0.688
```

Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.6831

```
        Sensitivity : 0.7778          
        Specificity : 0.9048          
     Pos Pred Value : 0.8750          
     Neg Pred Value : 0.8261          
         Prevalence : 0.4615          
     Detection Rate : 0.3590
```

Detection Prevalence : 0.4103
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.8413

```
   'Positive' Class : 0
```

Where I want to save `Accuracy` value for each element/model. This way I can compare each model specification with regard to accuracy.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `lapply(allModelsResults, predict, testing_data)`. If you have a list (of results) use a form of `*apply` to process it.

Comment: Thank you Rui Barradas, how would I go about storing specific results? From my `results_to_store` for example?

Comment: That depends. If what is extracted is a vector with a fixed length I use `sapply`. It will return a vector or matrix or similar object and these are in a tidy format easy to further process. Otherwise I use `lapply` and keep what is extracted in a list.

Comment: I am fairly new, and I do not understand exactly. Using your recommendation I would like to:
1st `store1 <- lapply(allModelsResults, predict, testing_data)`
2nd `store2 <- lapply(store1, confusionMatrix, testing_data$outcome)`
3rd extract the `Accuracy` value for each model/element and save.

This way I can compare each of my model accuracy and select the best one. That is the idea.

Comment: Use `[[` not `$` to access list elements. This works well with variables. `allModelResults[[1]]` is the first element, and if `i = 3` then `allModelResults[[i]]` is the third element.

Comment: And `lapply` always returns a `list`. You don't need to call it an "lapply object", it's just a list.

Comment: I would add that your example code is really confusing. We know you have an object called `allModelResults` with the models in it. You set up an object to put the results (`aggregate_results <- list()` would be better than `aggregate_results <- NULL`) - so far so good...

Comment: But then you don't mention anything you've referenced before in your code. I would expect you to start with something like `for (i in 1:length(allModelResults))`, but instead you start with `for(z in 1:length(categories))`. What is `categories`? Is it the same for all the models? Or is pulling `categories` out of `allModelResults` one of the things you need help with? What is `element_number_ID`? You use `element_number` as if it's defined already, what is it? And how is it different from `categories`? Why don't you reference the model at all?

Comment: Then you continue *"`element_number_ID` should equal `'1'` to extract the right model"*. This leaves me more confused. It seems like `z` iterates over the length of categories, so `z` is 1, 2, ..., `length(categories)`. Do you want `element_number_ID` to be the same as `z`? (If so, why not just use `z`? If not, how is it different?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want to get predictions and confusion matrix for each model. Without a reproducible example and with some confusion terminology, I'm doing a lot of guesswork, but I think I understand what you want (or close enough). I'll show you how I would do it with `lapply` and `Map`, and then we can do it with a `for` loop too.

First, get predictions on the testing data. All of these methods are exactly the same:

```
# lapply way
predictions = lapply(allModelsList, predict, newdata = testingdata)

# for loop way
predictions = list()
for (i in 1:length(allModelsList)) {
  predictions[[i]] = predict(allModelsList[[i]], newdata = testingdata)
}

# manual way - just so you understand exactly what's going on
predictions = list(
  predict(allModelsList[[1]], newdata = testingdata),
  predict(allModelsList[[2]], newdata = testingdata),
  predict(allModelsList[[3]], newdata = testingdata),
  ...
)
```

Now, `predictions` is a `list`, so we access each element with `[[`. The first one is `predictions[[1]]`, the `k`th one is `predictions[[k]]` if we want to define some variable `k` (like to use in loop). We could also add descriptive names and use the names instead of the indices.

Similarly, we can calculate all the confusion matrices:

```
# lapply way
conf_matrices = lapply(predictions, confusionMatrix, reference = testingdata$outcome)

# for loop way
conf_matrices = list()
for (p in 1:length(predictions)) {
  conf_matrices[[p]] = confusionMatrix(p, reference = testingdata$outcome)
}

# manual way (for illustration)
conf_matrices = list(
  confusionMatrix(predictions[[1]], reference = testingdata$outcome),
  confusionMatrix(predictions[[2]], reference = testingdata$outcome),
  ...
)
```

Again, we have a `list`. The first confusion matrix is `conf_matrices[[1]]` and all the same as above.

Hopefully that's helps us understand how to use `lapply` or a `for` loop to create a list.

---

Now, toward the bottom of your question you seem to imply that the `Accuracy` part of the confusion matrix. I ran the example at the bottom of the help page `?confusionMatrix` and looked at the result. Running `str(conf_mat)` on a result showed me that it is a `list`, and that the `"overall"` element of the list is a named vector, including the `"Accuracy"`. So, for an individual confusion matrix `cm` we can extract the accuracy with `cm[["overall"]]["Accuracy"]`. We use `[[` for the `list` part and `[` for the regular vector part. (We could also use `cm$overall["Accuracy"]`. `$` works when we give it the exact name, no quotes, no variables. A lot of your issues seem to be related to trying to use `$` with quotes or variables. You just can't do that. See `fortunes::fortune(312)`).

So, we can extract the accuracies from our confusion matrix list:

```
# I use *s*apply here so the result will be *s*implified into a vector
acc = sapply(conf_matrices, function(cm) cm[["overall"]]["Accuracy"])

acc = numeric(length(conf_matrices))
for (i in 1:length(conf_matrices)) {
  acc[i] = conf_matrices[[i]][["overall"]]["Accuracy"]
}
```

Or, if you know from the beginning you only want the accuracy, we could get there directly without saving the intermediate steps:

```
# apply
acc = sapply(allModelsList, function(x) {
    pred = predict(x, newdata = testingdata)
    cm = confusionMatrix(pred, reference = testingdata$outcome
    return(cm[["overall"]]["Accuracy"]
  }
)
```

# for loop
   acc = numeric(length(allModelsList)) 
   for (i in 1:length(allModelsList)) {
     pred = predict(allModelsList[[i]], newdata = testingdata)
     cm = confusionMatrix(pred, reference = testingdata$outcome
     acc[i] = (cm[["overall"]]["Accuracy"]
   }

---

Notes: As mentioned above, without a reproducible example I'm guessing quite a bit and *none of this is tested because I don't have any inputs to test on*. I'm presuming that what I see in your question in terms of individual steps, like that we want to predict on each element of `allModelResults`, are correct. (If so, it seems like, say, `fittedModels` would be a much better name than `allModelResults`.) I don't know what you mean by "model specifications", and I have no idea what's in `allModelList`, but hopefully this gives you enough examples of working with lists that you can work out any kinks. (There may also be, say, mismatched parentheses or missing brackets.)

`lapply` and `sapply` are convenient for letting you do less typing than a `for` loop, but they're not really any different. They set up an object to hold the results, and they fill it up. If you want to create multiple results at the same time, you may want to just us a `for` loop. And as the number of steps inside gets longer, it can be easier to debug a for loop anyway. Use what you like and what makes sense to you.

Comment: This answer is absolutely amazing. Indeed I am used to using data-frames with the $ usage.

Thank you for explaining each step so well. I hope this is useful for others as well

Comment: Note that using `[[` and `[` with variables works for data frames too. (Data frames are lists, just with a few extra properties.) So while `mtcars$mpg` is the `mpg` column from the `mtcars` data frame, if you have a column name in a variable `col = "mpg"`, then `mtcars$col` won't work.You can use `mtcars[, col]` or `mtcars[[col]]` - use `[[` when you know you want a single column only as a vector, use `[, col]` when you want possibly multiple columns.